# How to print and store specific named columns from csv file with new row numbers

Tags: bash, csv

start by saying, I'm very new to using bash and any sort of script writing in general.

I have a csv file that has basic column headers and values underneath which looks something like this as an example:

```
a  b  c  d
3  3  34 4
2  5  4  94
4  5  8  3
9  8  5  7
```

Is there a way to extract only the numerical values from a specific column and add a number for each row. For example first numbered row of the first column (starting from 1 after the column header) is 1, then 2, then 3, etc, for example for column b the output would be:

```
1  3
2  5
3  5
4  8
```

I would like to be able to do this for various different named column headers.

Any help would be appreciated,

Chris

Comment: I like to use CSVKit to parse my CSV files. It won't help you with the line numbers, though. https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? Using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print NR-1, $2}' file
1 3
2 5
3 5
4 8
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '              # using awk for the job
NR>1 {               # for the records or rows after the first
    print NR-1, $2   # output record number minus one and the second field or column
}' file              # state the file
```

*I would like to be able to do this for various different named column headers.* With awk you don't specify the column header name but the column number, like you don't state `b` but `$2`.

Comment: Can't improve on this... You can test if `$2` is numeric by `if ($2+0==$2)` if the OP means by  *Is there a way to extract only the numerical values from a specific column* to that he wants to test the field as numeric.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, thanks! Although for some reason when using that all the columns are in one column ($2), with nothing in the other columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR>1 {print i=1+i, $2}' file
```

`NR>1` skips the first line, in your case the header.

`print` print following

`i=1+i` prints i, i is first 0 and add 1, so i is 1, next time 2 and so on.

`$2` prints the second column.

`file` is the path to your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple multi-space delimited file (as in your example) `awk` is the best tool for the job. To select the column by name in `awk` you can do something like:

```
$ awk -v col="b" 'FNR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==col) x=i; next }
                  {print FNR-1 OFS $x}' file   
1 3
2 5
3 5
4 8
```